# AWS Textract - Analyzing PDF file with Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-textract

I'm having a hard time trying to use Textract in Lambda to analyze PDF document with javascript. I would really appreciate some help here.

Here is my code:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });

const textract = new AWS.Textract();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = decodeURIComponent(
    event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " ")
  );
  var textractParams = {
    DocumentLocation: {
      S3Object: {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Name: key,
      },
    },
    FeatureTypes: ["FORMS"]
  };
  
  try {
      const textractAnalysis = await textract.startDocumentAnalysis(textractParams);
      
      var analysisParams = {
        JobId: textractAnalysis.JobId
      };
      
      const data = await textract.getDocumentAnalysis(analysisParams);
      console.log(data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

This is the response I got:

```
  domain: null,
  service: Service {
    config: Config {
      credentials: [EnvironmentCredentials],
      credentialProvider: [CredentialProviderChain],
      region: 'eu-west-1',
      logger: null,
      apiVersions: {},
      apiVersion: null,
      endpoint: 'textract.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
      httpOptions: [Object],
      maxRetries: undefined,
      maxRedirects: 10,
      paramValidation: true,
      sslEnabled: true,
      s3ForcePathStyle: false,
      s3BucketEndpoint: false,
      s3DisableBodySigning: true,
      s3UsEast1RegionalEndpoint: 'legacy',
      s3UseArnRegion: undefined,
      computeChecksums: true,
      convertResponseTypes: true,
      correctClockSkew: false,
      customUserAgent: null,
      dynamoDbCrc32: true,
      systemClockOffset: 0,
      signatureVersion: 'v4',
      signatureCache: true,
      retryDelayOptions: {},
      useAccelerateEndpoint: false,
      clientSideMonitoring: false,
      endpointDiscoveryEnabled: undefined,
      endpointCacheSize: 1000,
      hostPrefixEnabled: true,
      stsRegionalEndpoints: 'legacy'
    },
    isGlobalEndpoint: false,
    endpoint: Endpoint {
      protocol: 'https:',
      host: 'textract.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
      port: 443,
      hostname: 'textract.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
      pathname: '/',
      path: '/',
      href: 'https://textract.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/'
    },
    _events: { apiCallAttempt: [Array], apiCall: [Array] },
    MONITOR_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: EVENTS_BUBBLE],
    CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE],
    _clientId: 3
  },
  operation: 'getDocumentAnalysis',
  params: { JobId: undefined },
  httpRequest: HttpRequest {
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/',
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'aws-sdk-nodejs/2.1001.0 linux/v14.18.1 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_nodejs14.x'
    },
    body: '',
    endpoint: {
      protocol: 'https:',
      host: 'textract.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
      port: 443,
      hostname: 'textract.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
      pathname: '/',
      path: '/',
      href: 'https://textract.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/',
      constructor: [Function]
    },
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    _userAgent: 'aws-sdk-nodejs/2.1001.0 linux/v14.18.1 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_nodejs14.x'
  },
  startTime: 2022-01-05T22:37:00.269Z,
  response: Response {
    request: [Circular *1],
    data: null,
    error: null,
    retryCount: 0,
    redirectCount: 0,
    httpResponse: HttpResponse {
      statusCode: undefined,
      headers: {},
      body: undefined,
      streaming: false,
      stream: null
    },
    maxRetries: 3,
    maxRedirects: 10
  },
  _asm: AcceptorStateMachine {
    currentState: 'validate',
    states: {
      validate: [Object],
      build: [Object],
      afterBuild: [Object],
      sign: [Object],
      retry: [Object],
      afterRetry: [Object],
      send: [Object],
      validateResponse: [Object],
      extractError: [Object],
      extractData: [Object],
      restart: [Object],
      success: [Object],
      error: [Object],
      complete: [Object]
    }
  },
  _haltHandlersOnError: false,
  _events: {
    validate: [
      [Function (anonymous)],
      [Function],
      [Function: VALIDATE_REGION],
      [Function: BUILD_IDEMPOTENCY_TOKENS],
      [Function: VALIDATE_PARAMETERS]
    ],
    afterBuild: [
      [Function: COMPUTE_CHECKSUM],
      [Function],
      [Function: SET_CONTENT_LENGTH],
      [Function: SET_HTTP_HOST]
    ],
    restart: [ [Function: RESTART] ],
    sign: [ [Function (anonymous)], [Function], [Function] ],
    validateResponse: [ [Function: VALIDATE_RESPONSE], [Function (anonymous)] ],
    send: [ [Function] ],
    httpHeaders: [ [Function: HTTP_HEADERS] ],
    httpData: [ [Function: HTTP_DATA] ],
    httpDone: [ [Function: HTTP_DONE] ],
    retry: [
      [Function: FINALIZE_ERROR],
      [Function: INVALIDATE_CREDENTIALS],
      [Function: EXPIRED_SIGNATURE],
      [Function: CLOCK_SKEWED],
      [Function: REDIRECT],
      [Function: RETRY_CHECK],
      [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT_RETRY]
    ],
    afterRetry: [ [Function] ],
    build: [ [Function: buildRequest] ],
    extractData: [ [Function: extractData], [Function: extractRequestId] ],
    extractError: [ [Function: extractError], [Function: extractRequestId] ],
    httpError: [ [Function: ENOTFOUND_ERROR] ],
    success: [ [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT] ],
    complete: [ [Function: API_CALL] ]
  },
  emit: [Function: emit],
  API_CALL_ATTEMPT: [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT],
  API_CALL_ATTEMPT_RETRY: [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT_RETRY],
  API_CALL: [Function: API_CALL]
}
```

But when I change both textract functions and add promise like this:

```
const textractAnalysis = await textract.startDocumentAnalysis(textractParams).promise();
const data = await textract.getDocumentAnalysis(analysisParams).promise();
```

Then I get this response:

```
{ JobStatus: 'IN_PROGRESS', AnalyzeDocumentModelVersion: '1.0' }
```

I also tried to use Textract Client but that was even worse because I can't import it at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably the asynchronous analysis has not yet completed at the time you call `getDocumentAnalysis`. What `JobStatus` is present in the response?

Comment: @jarmod I updated the post, I've got some responses but nothing positive still.

Comment: Not sure what else you're expecting to see here. It's an async task. It's in progress. You have to wait until it's complete, at which time the text extraction results will be available to you. You can subscribe to a supplied SNS topic to be notified, if you prefer not to poll.

Comment: @jarmod I managed to get response blocks after I created separate lambda which was triggered by SNS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Documentation of `.startDocumentAnalysis` shows that you only get the jobId as response.

> When text analysis is finished, Amazon Textract publishes a completion
> status to the Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) topic
> that you specify in NotificationChannel.

> To get the results of the text analysis operation, first check that
> the status value published to the Amazon SNS topic is SUCCEEDED. If
> so, call GetDocumentAnalysis, and pass the job identifier (JobId) from
> the initial call to StartDocumentAnalysis. For more information, see
> Document Text Analysis.

If you want a more or less synchronous way of doing it you can use `.analyzeDocument`.

Comment: The synchronous request would not be a good option from a Lambda function.